# Local web application without web server and access to SQLite

Tags: sqlite, web-applications, browser, desktop-application, local-storage

I want to develop an [ERP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_resource_planning) system, but I want it to run on a web browser. I want it to store data in an SQLite database, but I don't want it to have to work as client/server, just local.

I also want to have access to environment variables and the filesystem. Ultimately I want to manipulate the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) using C instead of JavaScript.

Is there a browser, framework or library for this?

Comment: Why would you want to make local application in web browser if you specifically require to break all security layers of web browser anyway?

Comment: Browser security layer is intended to prevent attacks from external sources from the Interent, I want a web browser wich can't browse the Internet, just local files.

Comment: So why complicate things this way? I understand people who like to make things all in HTML and JS but you said you want to manipulate DOM through C language. In .net you can make application with webbrowser component and manipulate dom through .net, but its based on IE and its almost equivalent of writing your own browser, but may be there are plugins that can let third party applications use browser the way you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, it's impossible to manipulate the DOM with any language other than JavaScript - since that is the only programming language which the **browser** will run.

I would try to think of one of the following:

1) Run a local web server - why shouldn't you? I am not sure about C, but  Python, Ruby, JS and many other languages make these extremely simple to set up.

2) Just write a GUI application, if you are really opposed to having another program running in the network.

3) If you're not opposed to Python (instead of C), you can try out [Pyjamas](http://pyjs.org/) - a framework which allows you to code a web-app in Python, and use it as a desktop app later (without running the server). The non-server version won't actually run inside a browser though (AFAIK - I've never tried it myself).